# Conditional statement in beforeEach

Tags: cypress

most of my tests need to do one task before start so I made beforeEach function that works perfect.

One test need to do something else before start.

Is in Cypress some way to do beforeEach except some tests?

I am trying to add cypress.current.title swtich case statement

Answer (score 4):

Using [Cypress.currentTest](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/currenttest) to modify the code of `beforeEach()` would be something like this:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  if (!Cypress.currentTest.title !== 'Without login') {
    cy.login()
  }
})

it('Without login', () => {
  // run without logging in
})
```

Or with partial name check

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  if (!Cypress.currentTest.title.includes('without login')) {
    cy.login()
  }
})

it('Tests something without login', () => {
  // run without logging in
})
```

Or for describe block use `titlePath`

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  if (!Cypress.currentTest.titlePath.includes('Without login')) {
    cy.login()
  }
})

describe('Without login', () => {
  // run without logging in

  it('redirects to login page', () => {

  })

  it('rejects invalid credentials', () => {

  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to add [per-test configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Test-specific-Configuration) to use in the `beforeEach()`.

This works because Cypress first scans the test code in a setup phase, then runs the code.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  if (Cypress.config('tag') === 'skip-startup-task') {
    return
  }

  // run startup task
})

it('Runs with no setup', {tag: 'skip-startup-task'}, () => {

})
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to [pass in the environment variable to the test configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-5-Test-Configuration), allowing you to run a switch statement or another control based on that. In my example below, I'm simply using a boolean `useFoo`, and having two separate paths. If there are additional ones that will be needed, then a `switch` statement like you mention may be the way to go.

```js
describe('tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    if (Cypress.env('useFoo')) {
      // code
    } else {
      // code
    }
  });

  it('tests using foo', { env: { useFoo: true } }, () => { ... });

  it('tests not using foo', { env: { useFoo: false } }, () => { ... }); 
});
```